C++ operator== doesn't work but an actual function does
I got a function:
bool equal(int var, std::initializer_list<int> list)
{
    return std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), var) != list.end();
}

which works, I got no error when I use the function.
But when I create an operator overload with the same parameters, it gives me an compiling error E0029 when using the operator ==.
bool operator==(int var, std::initializer_list<int> list)
{
    return std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), var) != list.end();
}

The function definitions don't give me errors, it's when I call the operator with the parameters that it does.
Here's the full thing:
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>



bool operator==(int var, std::initializer_list<int> list)
{
    return std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), var) != list.end();
}
bool equal(int var, std::initializer_list<int> list)
{
    return std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), var) != list.end();
}

int main()
{
    bool b;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        b = (i == {1,2,3});    // this line gives me a compiling error
        b = equal(i, {1,2,3}); // this line doesn't
        if (b) std::cout << "true\n";
        else std::cout << "false\n";
    }
    return 0;
}


If I put the i == {1,2,3} directly in the "if" it doesn't change anything.
Putting brackets around the list, like i == ({1,2,3}), doesn't change anything neither.

I tried using another software, I'm currently using Visual Studio Code 22, and I tried compiling it in Codeblocks and in Linux with gcc, it gives me an error the same way.
Codeblocks:
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
test.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
test.cpp|113|error: expected primary-expression before '{' token|
test.cpp|113|error: expected ')' before '{' token|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

In gcc with the command "gcc test.cpp -o test.exe":
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:113:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
  113 |         b = (i == {1,2,3});
      |                   ^
test.cpp:113:18: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘{’ token
  113 |         b = (i == {1,2,3});
      |             ~    ^~
      |                  )


{1,2,3} by itself is not an std::initializer_list, it has no type at all.

That's a very surprising notion of equality.

operator==(i, {1,2,3}) compiles, too.

Basically, The language grammar only allows a braced list in certain grammatical contexts, not in place of an arbitrary expression. and also see Can operators be overloaded for initializer_list literals?. Also operator==(i, {1,2,3}) should work as described in the second dupe.

You should thank the compiler for not allowing you to use a nonsensical definition of ==.  Using a function is a better idea in this case, although I'd name it in or contains instead of equal.

An initializer_list can be used for the right operand of assignment, or for a function call argument.  i == {1,2,3} is neither of those two things.  The operator==(i, {1,2,3}) is one of those two things.
